# JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML Table:

```
<table class="display" style="width: 1000px;" id="failoverServers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="row_selector_head"> <input type='checkbox' class='select_all_chkbx'/></th>
            <th><div>{% trans "IP ADDRESS" %}</div></th>
            <th><div>{% trans "VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS" %}</div></th>
            <th><div>{% trans "USERNAME" %}</div></th>
            <th><div></div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for i in list %}
        <tr rel="{{ i.id }}">
            <td class="row_selector"><input type='checkbox'/></td>
            <td rel="ip">{{ i.ipAddress }}</td>
            <td rel="virtualIP">{{ i.virtualIpAddress }}</td>
            <td rel="username">{{ i.username }}</td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I do the following:

```
var list = "";
            $('#failoverServers td.row_selector.selected').each(function() {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var id = row.attr('rel');
            list += id + " ";           
        });
```

Then I have a list of the numbers in the very first checkbox column.

I want to get a list of the following from the table:

```
<td rel="ip">{{ i.ipAddress }}</td>
```

What jquery selector do I use for this??

Thanks

Comment: What is "rel" as it related to the TD tag?

Comment: To reiterate what @SteveH. said, rel is not a valid attribute of td and I wouldn't rely heavily on it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td#Attributes

Comment: To reinforce what @gerges said, maybe you should be using "data-rel" instead, since that is the "approved" way to attach data to dom nodes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: OP, please consider accepting an answer, not accepting an answer or not telling us if your problem was resolved is considered bad manners, it is unlikely to help future users who will read this questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = [];

$('#failoverServers td.row_selector.selected').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    list.push($(row).children("td[rel=ip]")[0].text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments.
I have got the following working:

```
 var list = [];
  $('#failoverServers td.row_selector.selected').each(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var serverIp = row.find('td[rel=ip]').text();
        list += serverIp + " ";         
    });
```

What I want to do is to just get all the ip items from the table whether they are selected or now (Just get all them)
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working example (static so that I could test). Place your template placeholders accordingly and change your markup (if you want to be standarts complient): your table header contains 5 cells, but td's in the rows are just 4, divs should not be placed in td s - my IDE is screaming :) and these 'rel's - why do you use them - rels should be used in links. I think "id" and "class" are sufficient to achieve everything you need ("id's" for unique elements, "class" for as many as you want).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery181min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

        var values = '';    
            $('input:checkbox:checked.row_selector').parent().siblings(".ip").each(function() {
            values += '  ' + $(this).text();    
            });

        console.log(values);
        });    

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table class="display" style="width: 1000px;" id="failoverServers" border =1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="row_selector_head"> <input type='checkbox' name="name" value="asdf" class='select_all_chkbx' checked="checked"/></th>
                <th>IP Address</th>
                <th>Virtual Ip Address</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr id="id1">
                <td><input class="row_selector" type='checkbox' name="name" value="val1" checked="checked" /></td>
                <td class="ip">123.123.123.123</td>
                <td class="virtualIP">55.55.55.55</td>
                <td class="username">Jean Valzean</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="id2">
                <td><input class="row_selector" type='checkbox' name="name" value="val2"/></td>
                <td class="ip">125.125.125.124</td>
                <td class="virtualIP">22.22.22.22</td>
                <td class="username">Peter Meter</td>
            </tr>
                    <tr id="id3">
                <td><input class="row_selector" type='checkbox' name="name" value="val3" checked="checked" /></td>
                <td class="ip">192.168.33.24</td>
                <td class="virtualIP">33.33.33.33</td>
                <td class="username">Joe Schmoe</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And result is:
[image: jquery selected td data retrieval result]